# Nginx Mail Proxy: Can I pass extra headers on auth_http option to authenticate the proxy

Tags: nginx, email-server

Hello I want to somehow on my custom script that nginx uses to auth the email address to pass some extra headers in order somehow to authenticate the mail proxy itself, therefore no other mail proxies except the authorized ones will get provided with a response.

Do you know how somehow I will pass my own headers to the script I wanna to answer. For example I have the following setup:

```
mail {
    server_name mail.example.com;
    auth_http   192.16.45.126:9000/cgi-bin/nginxauth.cgi;

    proxy_pass_error_message on;

    ssl                 on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/server.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    server {
        listen     25;
        protocol   smtp;
        smtp_auth  login plain cram-md5;
    }

    server {
        listen    110;
        protocol  pop3;
        pop3_auth plain apop cram-md5;
}

     server {
        listen   143;
        protocol imap;
    }
}
```

So let suppose that the script located in `192.16.45.126:9000/cgi-bin/nginxauth.cgi` needs theese extra auth headers:

> proxy_user : where I set a username for the proxy
>
> proxy_pass : where I set a password for the proxy

So proxies and replicating requests should need to get authenticated with the provided username and password first and afterwards will process the authentication request for the user. So no other request will get further processed except the ones that come from authorized proxies.

Do you know if that is feasible and how I can coinfigure the nginx to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use auth_http_header, from [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_auth_http_module.html#auth_http_header):

> Syntax:   auth_http_header header value; Default: — Context:  mail,
>   server Appends the specified header to requests sent to the
>   authentication server. This header can be used as the shared secret to
>   verify that the request comes from nginx. For example:
>
> `auth_http_header X-Auth-Key "secret_string";`

Then in your script, you can check that the content of the header X-Auth-Key contains the value that you expected